Reading and interpreting supply and demand curve
I have just been introduced to the topic of supply and demand curves in my mathematical modelling course. When we read the curve, we often say "an increase or decrease in the price results in so and so happening." My issue with this is that we tend to interpret the graph by analysing it in both directions (i.e., right to left and left to right), unlike the way we typically read the graph of a function, which is left to right. An example is when we look at rate of change or concavity.
Why is it that we can read the supply and demand curve in such a way since it has been graphed using functions? What am I missing?
EDIT:
Has this got anything to do with the fact that the independent variable, price, is written on the y axis?


An example (any such function with its graph) will be very helpful

Your presumption at the edit is right. The price is the independent variable here. The firms have a demand curve along the marginal cost function. The marginal cost then defines the quantity the firms produces. The demand curve: The higher the price the lower is the demanded quantity. Again: The quantity follows the price level. Contrary to the practice in math the independent variable is on the y-axis and the dependen variable is on the x-axis. So we have here indeed something special.

Just as a line or curve is a set of points, the supply and demand curves above are the sets of all possible supply amounts and demand amounts.  We generally only really "read" the graph of a function from left to right when determining whether its slope is positive or negative, or if it really only makes sense to read it in one direction (such as "prices over time" or "units sold over time").  Since both supply and demand can either increase or decrease at any time (and can be independent of one another), and there isn't necessarily a direct or inverse relationship between them, it makes sense that the graph could be read in both directions.

thank you for your reply. The part where you said that supply and demand can be independent of each other and so it makes sense it can be read in both directions. What happens when they are not independent of one another? Does the same thing apply? If so, why or why not?

^I'm not entirely sure and you may be able to make an argument either way.  Let's say half the houses in a town of 6000 people are destroyed in a fire but everyone was able to evacuate.  Before there were 6000 people needing housing and (let's say the average house has 3 people) 2000 homes.  After there are 6000 people needing housing and 1000 homes.  On one hand, the demand remains the same regardless of the supply so they would appear independent.  On the other hand, there's going to be much more unmet immediate demand caused by the new supply shortage and they'll have to move temporarily.

Part 2: If a different town builds housing, it may increase demand if a lot of people want to move to that town but it may have no effect on demand if it's an ugly, polluted town few people want to move to if they can help it.  If they desperately need housing regardless of affordability or location that's inelastic demand.  Obviously it gets complicated.

(When they have to move temporarily it increases demand in other towns/cities).  But I'm by no means an expert on all things economics so I'd try to find someone who is.

I'd post this on economics.stackexchange
